# Adapting an async method with closure to a syncronous method with return type

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, closures

I'm new to swift and not overly experienced in any major threading work, so I'm try to improve my skills a bit, hoping for a bit of help or guidance. This is one concept I can't seem to figure out.

I have a class which does communication via an Input and Output stream, the app sends via the output stream, and reads the result from the input stream. Right now I have created the method to send async via callbacks, but I would like the ability to send synchronously, and handle the threading at a higher level.
Currently my communication method looks something like this:

```
typealias CommunicationCallback = ((CommunicationResult) -> Void)

func sendAsync(send message: String, closure: @escaping CommunicationCallback) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            let messagePair = MessagePair(SendReceiveResult(sent: message, received: nil),
                                  closure)

            strongSelf.writeQueue.enqueue(messagePair)
            strongSelf.writeFromQueue() //Calls the CommunicationCallback closure after it has read result
        }

}

func sendSyncronized(send message: String) -> CommunicationResult {
    ???
}
```

Is there a general way to wrap a async all like that above?
In case I am thinking of this totally wrong, what Id' like in some cases to simply be able to call

```
let result = sendSyncronized("foo")
```

instead of doing

```
send("foo", closure: { result in
    switch result {
    case .a:
        foo()
    base .b:
        bar()
    }
})
```

everytime, as there are some cases in which I need to do many sequential writes while waiting for the previous result.
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use an optional return type.

```
typealias CommunicationCallback = ((CommunicationResult) -> Type?)
```

return nil in async method and the value in synchronous method. Use **if let** to check if the optional binding is successful. If not, you need to get the value from closure anyway.